can't find the the app version on Play store
I want to get the app version from play store but can't find it anymore,
I know there are similar questions already on this site but none of them works anymore.
there is not any of these classes: "hAyfc" ,"htlgb" or "softwareversion"
Atm the only thing that I can find is the date it uploads:
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AppName");


                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(content);

                    HtmlNode divNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='xg1aie']");
                    string updatedOn = divNode.InnerText.Trim();
                    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(updatedOn, "MMMM d, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    string version = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    return version;

                }


AFAIK all solutions to this download the apps store listing and parse the HTML to find the version.  Even if you get this to work, it will break every time the play store layout changes.  The best approach oils be to host your own file somewhere that contains latest version information
